What will be the next Sonarqube LTS version?
I cannot find information about the next Sonarqube LTS version.
SonarQube LTA release happens approximately every 18 months. The more frequent releases of SonarQube, where the product progressively introduces new features and enhancements occur every 2-3 months.
The current LTA is SonarQube 9.9 released in February 2023.
Do you know what will be the next Sonarqube LTS version?

You'd probably get a better answer from the people at SonarQube, though I suspect the answer would be "When it's ready.".
